# Stopping VMs in Azure when CPU usage is lower than 10%

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, runbook, azure-runbook

Is there a way to script something using runbooks in Azure so that a script runs that checks the CPU Usage and if the average for two hours is less than 10% it shuts down the VM?

Has anyone got an example script?

Comment: Hey! i'm looking for the same thing. Were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have example code, but would start with Azure Monitor. Using Azure Monitor you can create an alerts with specific criteria such as CPU usage and a time slice.

[Create, view, and manage alerts using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-alerts-unified-usage?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-nepeters)

On alert you can engage an Azure Automation Web-hook to perform the remediation action.

[Webhook actions for alert rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-alerts-unified-log-webhook?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-nepeters)

Answer (score 0):

Azure alert rules are probably the way to go here. Here's an [end-to-end solution](https://azurebro.com/2019/04/16/auto-stop-your-vm-based-on-cpu-utilization-azure-automation/) with that.

A simpler way to do it is using a tool like [VMPower](https://vmpower.com) which  isn't free but is inexpensive and works best when you need to do this across multiple VMs with different auto-stop configurations.